# Creating a Delegate from methodInfo in Mono 2.8.2

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, mono

Hi I am trying to create a messenger in Mono 2.8.2 - the subset used by Unity3d. I thought it would be nifty to create a helper to auto subscribe methods to the messenger when they are decorated with a "subscribe" attribute.

I've been scratching my head over this and have read many of the other related stack questions without a solution to my problem. [Frankly, I don't know if I am doing something wrong or if this is a bug in Mono.](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2010-December/106824.html)

```
foreach (var methodInfo in methods)
        {
            var attr = methodInfo.GetAttribute<SubscribeAttribute>();
            if (attr == null)
                continue;

            var parmas = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            if (parmas.Length != 1)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Subscription aborted. Invalid paramters.");
                continue;
            }

            var type = parmas[0].ParameterType;

            // Crashes here
            // ArgumentException: method argument length mismatch
            // I have tried many combinations.. 
            // Direct typing of the message type and dynamic typing

            var action = (Action<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object>), methodInfo);

             // also does not work
             // var dt = Expression.GetActionType(parmas.Select(o => o.ParameterType).ToArray());
             // var action = Delegate.CreateDelegate(dt, methodInfo);

            Subscribe(type, action, instance);
        }
```

Any suggestions or work around would be appreciated.

**Edit**
The method signature looks like :

```
[Subscribe]
void OnMessage(object message){
  // Hello World
}
```

Though, it was originally...

```
[Subscribe]
void OnTestMessage(TestMessage message){
  // Hello World
}
```

Comment: What's the signature of the method you're trying to subscribe to? Does it have a signature like `void MyMethod(object arg)`?

Comment: Correct. I have updated the post.

Comment: mono 2.8 is extremely old, please upgrade to 3.2.3

Comment: @knocte: Not an option.  Unity uses the version of mono Unity uses (technically this fork: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono) and that's that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a non-static method and you didn't provide a target object.  Therefore `Delegate.CreateDelegate` will create an "open delegate" with an explicit `this` argument.

Because of the required `this` argument, it no longer matches the signature.

Comment: I get myself wound up over an issue and miss the obvious. I need to learn to lay off the coffee and go play with my cat.

Comment: It‘s been a long time but this answer really helps. `(Action<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object>), **this**, methodInfo);` will make it right.